# Update WZBitmap using WZBitmap.setBitmap() got black overlayview

Tags: android, wowza

I download `gocoder` android example and run the `BitmapOverlayActivity`, everything is ok but when I try to update the WZBitmap using  `WZBitmap.setBitmap()` like:

```
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (mWZBitmap != null) {
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() % 2 == 0) {
                mWZBitmap.setBitmap(overlayBitmap1);
            } else {
                mWZBitmap.setBitmap(overlayBitmap2);
            }
        }
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
    }
};

private Handler handler = new Handler();
```

and the camera only shows black view:

[image]